# Why does $httpBackend not respond?

Tags: angularjs, mocking, jasmine, httpbackend

I'm having difficulty learning to unit test some AngularJS code using Karma and am getting hung up on the use of $httpBackend.  I've created a distilled version of the test, showing only where I mock the get request and expect to see a non-failing call to `httpBackend.get(...)`.

```js
describe('Basics', function() {
    var httpBackend;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function($httpBackend) {
        httpBackend = $httpBackend;
        httpBackend.when("GET", "/foo.json").respond("{\"name\":\"value\"}");
    }));

    it('should complete this task', function() {
        console.log(httpBackend);
        var getFoo = httpBackend.get("/foo.json"); // line 11
        httpBackend.flush();
    });
});
```

It's failing on line 11.  Here's what I see in my logs.

```
LOG: function $httpBackend(method, url, data, callback, headers, timeout, withCredentials) { ... }
Chrome 36.0.1985 (Mac OS X 10.9.4) Basics should complete this task FAILED
    TypeError: undefined is not a function
        at null.<anonymous> (/path/to/app/main/httptest.js:11:30)
Chrome 36.0.1985 (Mac OS X 10.9.4): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.023 secs / 0.021 secs)
```

What am I missing?

[EDIT: Here's where I went wrong... I was treating $httpBackend as though it were a mock of $http, when it's not.  The following code succeeds.]

```
describe('Basics', function() {
    var httpBackend;
    var http;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function($httpBackend, $http) {
        httpBackend = $httpBackend;
        http = $http;
        httpBackend.when("GET", "/foo.json").respond("{\"name\":\"value\"}");
    }));

    it('should complete this task', function() {
        console.log(httpBackend);
        var getFoo=http.get("/foo.json") // line 11
            .success(function(data) {})
            .error(function() {});
        httpBackend.flush();
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the documentation for $httpBackend says, then you cannot use a method called "get".
"get" is only when using $http

You should instead use "expectGet"

```
httpBackend.expectGET('/foo.json');
```

Comment: I understand $httpBackend to be a mock for $http.  When $http.get is invoked, it should actually be invoking $httpBackend.get under the covers, no?

Comment: You're right.  I misunderstood the relationship between $http and $httpBackend.